# My vs code changed the colors of my flutter project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Here is the example: https://i.imgur.com/0yW16kP.mp4

From today my functions started to look green, and I want to change it back, to the original blue, you can saw it when I open the file. I didn't make any change

Answer (score 2):

On VSCode go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Color Theme** .. And select it to **Dark+ (default dark)**

Comment: in Mac, It will be Code > Preferences > Color Theme